# What are the prevailing winds on a tidally locked ocean planet?

Tags: planetary-science, climate, tidal-locking

I am trying to picture the atmospheric circulation of a tidally locked planet, similar to Earth in mass and atmosphere.

The rotational axis would need to be (roughly) perpendicular to the ecliptic if it is tidally locked. The sub solar point would be HOT, creating an ascending nexus for a Hadley cell. The anti-solar point (COLD) would be the descending nexus. Things get complicated around the poles with the (small) Coriolis force due to the slow rotation.

From https://astrobiology.com/2022/04/atmospheric-dynamics-of-a-near-tidally-locked-earth-size-planet.html:

> discovery and characterization of Earth-sized planets that are in, or
> near, a tidally-locked state are of crucial importance to
> understanding terrestrial planet evolution … terrestrial exoplanet
> demographics are heavily biased toward short-period planets, many of
> which are expected to be tidally locked …

[image]

In an idealized situation, with an all-ocean planet, what would the prevailing surface winds be?
For bonus points, how about if the planet is tidally locked to a gas giant instead of the star?

Edit: Here is an interesting paper on the topic: https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.2022705118

[image]

Comment: Obligatory reference to the planet [We Made It](https://larryniven.fandom.com/wiki/We_Made_It) in Larry Niven's "Known Space" stories. Its rotational axis is in the plane of Procyon's ecliptic, yielding absurd winds half the year -- I've no idea how meteorologically plausible this is.

Comment: @RussellBorogove ... Niven is totally kewl. I'll need to chase it down.  But I think most tidally locked planets will have axis roughly perpendicular to the ecliptic due to precession / tidal vodoo.

Comment: Is there ice at dark side of the ocean planet?

Comment: Maybe you could look for some publication from the 1950ies: Back than it was assumed, that mercury is tidal locked to the sun and has a thick atmosphere.

Comment: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/4850/how-would-winds-behave-on-a-tidally-locked-planet

Comment: IIRC the computer simulations about ten years ago gave surprising results -- what they had expected were extreme winds with a vertical loop (cold sunward winds at the surface and warm nightward wind at altitude), which is what Niven and others predicted, but in practice the loops very quickly "fell over" to produce semi-permanent cyclonic systems that were actually not crazy, just like constant 30-40 mph wind (which is pretty breezy but nothing you couldn't walk in). So you'd actually have prevailing winds much like the Pacific tradewinds, where the direction is a function of latitude.